# How to create a single html from Jekyll documentation (for offline usage)?

Tags: html, jekyll

We use [Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/) for creating our online documentation.

We wish to compile a single `HTML` file to act as a local/offline version of the online documentation. This we would then like to distribute to end users that may sometimes be without internet access.

Are there any plugins/libraries that can help facilitate such a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project [`jekyll-docs`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-docs) exists for a similar reason — to provide documentation offline.